# Over $\mathbb{R}$, if $Z(p') \subset Z(p)$ when does $p' \vert p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm mainly wondering about the planar case, when $p', p \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. For instance the simplest case would be when $Z(p')$ is a line contained in $Z(p)$, does it follow that $p' \vert p$? I know that over an algebraically closed field the answer would be yes by the Nullstellensatz, but I don't know anything about the real case.

EDIT: Based on the comments I will ask something more concrete:

> Let $p \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ be irreducible and $p' = x$ so that $Z(p')$ is the $y$-axis.
>
> If $Z(p') \subset Z(p)$ do we necessarily have $p' \vert p$ (i.e. $x \vert p$)?

Comment: What about polynomials like $x^2+1$ or $x^2+y^2+1$?

Comment: @Lubin Thanks, I guess I was assuming $Z(p')$ was non empty, so I would still like to know what happens in this case

Comment: If you assume $p$ and $p^\prime$ are irreducible the answer should be yes, because then you an inclusion of principal ideals. Otherwise you have things like $p^\prime=x^4$ and $p=x$.

Comment: @JSchlather I think that in that case we have $p' \in I(Z(p))$ and $\langle p \rangle \subset I(Z(p))$ but I don't see why $I(Z(p))$ is principal? (i.e. why it is $\langle p \rangle$)

Comment: @user65254 Sorry, I was mixing up what does and doesn't hold when the field is algebraically closed.

Comment: No worries, most references seem to just deal with the algebraically closed case so I'm having trouble with working over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If $x$ divides $p$, then $p$ is not irreducible.

Comment: @Hagen indeed, if $x \vert p$ then $x = p$, but I left it phrased as in the first part of the question

Comment: Consider the Clebsch cubic surface $X$ given by the irreducible polynomial $x^3+y^3+z^3+1-(x+y+z+1)^3$. Then the line $(x,-x,-1)$ lies on $X$. Through an affine coordinate transformation one can shift $X$ such that this line becomes the $y$-axis. Thus one gets an irreducible polynomial $p(x,y,z)$ of degree $3$ such that the $y$-axis lies in $Z(p)$.

In general on a smooth cubic algebraic surface one can find 27 lines. However even if the surface is defined over the reals, some of the lines may not. But the above argument works whenever at least one line is real.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $p(x,y)=p_0(y)+xp_1(x,y)$ with $p_0(y)\in\mathbb R[y]$. Then for all $b\in \mathbb R$, $p_0(b)=p(0,b)=0$. So $p_0\equiv 0$ and $p\in x\mathbb R[x,y]$.

A more general question is : let $I, I'$ be ideals of $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ such that $Z(I')\subseteq Z(I)$, under which condition we have $I\subseteq \sqrt{I'}$ ? A trivial sufficient condition is $I'$ satisfies Nullstellensatz, i.e. if the set $\mathcal I(Z(I'))$ of polynomials vanishing at $Z(I')$, is equal to $\sqrt{I'}$. This condition is also necessary if we want the above conclusion to hold for all $I$ (take $I=\mathcal I(Z(I'))$).

> Claim: If $Z(I')\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is Zariski dense in $Z(I'\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n])\subseteq \mathbb C^n$ (equivalently, the real points of $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n]/I')$ are Zariski dense in the complex points), then $I'$ satisfies Nullstellensatz.

Example: if $I'=(x_1)$. Then $I'$ satisfies Nullstellensatz.

Proof of the claim: let $f\in \mathcal I(Z(I'))$. In $\mathbb C^n$, $Z(f)$ contains $Z(I')\subseteq \mathbb R^n$. By hypothesis, this implies that $Z(f)\supseteq Z(I'\mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n])$. Hence by Nullstellensatz, $f^m\in I'\mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ for some $m\ge 1$:
$$f^m=\sum_{i} g_i z_i, \quad g_i\in I', z_i\in \mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n].$$
Taking the real parts in this equality we get $f^m\in I'$.

> *Proposition* (Generalization of the above example). Suppose the complex variety $Z(I'\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n])$ is irreducible, and its smooth locus contains a real point. Then $I'$ satisfies Nullstellensatz.

**EDIT** Idea of the proof: the scheme $X:=\mathrm{Spec} (\mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n]/I')$ is irreducible and smooth at a rational point $P$. By general results, restricting $X$ to a Zariski open neighborhood of $P$ (this doesn't change the property that real points are Zariski dense) there exists an étale morphism $f : X\to \mathbb A^d_{\mathbb R}$ such that $f(P)=0$. By implicit function theorem, there exists a (real) open neighborhood $V$ of $0$ and a real open neighborhood $U$ of $P$ such that $f|_U : U(\mathbb R)\to V(\mathbb R)$ is an isomorphism of real manifolds. If $X(\mathbb R)$ was not Zariski dense, it would be contained in some hypersurface $Z(g)$ (in scheme-theoretical sense, or think of complex points) with $g\ne 0$. The image $f(Z(g))$ has Krull dimension $<d$ hence contained in $Z(h)$ for some $h\in \mathbb R[t_1,\dots, t_d]$. As
$$V(\mathbb R)\subseteq f(X(\mathbb R))\subseteq Z(h)(\mathbb R),$$ 
and $V(\mathbb R)$ contains a set of the form $I_1\times ...\times I_d$ with 
$I_i$ non-empty open intervals, this forces $h$ to be zero. Contradiction.

**EDIT 2** Reference: Bochnak-Coste-Roy: Real algebraic geometry, Chapter 4. 
An ideal $I$ of $\mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is called a *real ideal* if for any $f_1, \dots, f_s\in \mathbb R[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ such that $f_1^2+\cdots+f_s^2\in I$, we have $f_1, \dots, f_s\in I$.

> Theorem 4.1.4: $I$ satisfies nullstellensatz ($I=\mathcal I(Z(I))$) if and only if $I$ is real.

Related to Proposition above is

> Theorem 4.5.1 (iii): $f\in \mathbb R[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ generates a real ideal if and only if the hypersurface $Z(f)$ has a smooth real point.

Comment: this is fantastic, thank you! I'd love to have a reference or elaboration for your last paragraph, if it's not too much trouble

Comment: @Loadge: I think this should be well-known. But I don't know much about real algebraic geometry, so I don't have a reference. I will try to write something here later.

Comment: much appreciated, don't worry if you can't get around to it, the rest of your answer has been very useful =)

Comment: Now I found a reference !

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I didn't catch your first edit yesterday. Wish I could +vote you again!