# An easy proof that $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$ is irreducible in the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be an infinite field (that is not necessarily algebraically closed) and consider the algebraic variety $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)=\mathcal{V}(\det-1)$ of $F^{n^2}$, where
$$\mathcal{V}(S)=\{\alpha\in F^k\,|\,f(\alpha)=0\ \forall f\in S\}.$$
We say that a Zariski-closed subset $X$ of $F^{n^2}$ is irreducible, i.e., that if there are two non-empty, proper, Zariski-closed subsets $X_1,X_2$ of $F^{n^2}$ such that $X=X_1\cup X_2$, then $X\subseteq X_i$ for some $i=1,2$.

> Is there an easy proof that $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$ is irreducible?

I tried following [these notes](http://www.shsu.edu/ldg005/data/689/Old.pdf) (see Example 2.25), but I can't quite understand their method. Basically, the proof there says that $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$ is irreducible if and only if $\det-1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $n^2$ variables.

As mentioned in Theorem 2.27 of the notes, an algebraic variety $X\subseteq F^k$ is irreducible if and only if its ideal $$\mathcal{I}(X)=\{f\in F[x_1,\ldots,x_k]\,|\,f(\alpha)=0\ \forall \alpha\in X\}$$ is prime, so what I really need is a proof that the ideal of $\mathcal{V}(\det-1)$ is prime. Hence, what I'm really asking is this:

> Why does irreducibility of $\det-1$ imply that the ideal $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(\det-1))$ is prime?
>
> EDIT: This also answers the question: [Over $\mathbb{R}$, if $Z(p') \subset Z(p)$ when does $p' \vert p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323234/over-mathbbr-if-zp-subset-zp-when-does-p-vert-p)

Comment: In a unique factorization domain, a principal ideal generated by an irreducible element is prime. The ideal $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(\det-1))$ is the radical of the ideal $(\det-1)$, which is $(\det-1)$ itself whenever $(\det-1)$ is prime.

Comment: But aren't we only allowed to say that $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(\det-1))$ is the radical of $(\det-1)$ if we're working within an algebraically closed field?

Comment: @Servaes: I need the result for $F=\mathbb{R}$ at the very least, so Hilbert's Nullstellensatz doesn't apply (as far as I can see).

Comment: If your field isn't algebraically closed, then you should be careful about what you mean by $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(\det-1))$. What are your definitions of $\mathcal{V}(I)$ and $\mathcal{I}(V)$ for ideals $I$ and algebraic sets $V$?

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry about that! I'll edit my original question.

Comment: Also, it means to me that there might be some overtly special property of $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$ that makes it work. There exist polynomials $f\in\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $\mathcal{V}(f)$ is reducible. Does it even hold at all, I wonder?

Comment: The link to the notes has expired.

Comment: @Shaun: the example comes from ‪lecture notes by Luis David Garcia Puente, by the name of "Affine varieties and examples", and it doesn't seem like they are available any place else online. You are welcome to write me if you need a copy, but I also included the proof in my master's thesis (Prop. 6.2.7): https://math.ananas.nu/artikler/Simplicity_and_uniqueness_of_trace_Revision.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that some special properties of SL$_n$ are needed.

First some counterexamples in the general case.

1. If $F=\mathbb Q$. Consider $x^3+y^3-1\in \mathbb Q[x,y]$. It is an irreducible polynomial, but its zero set is finite and reducible.
2. Over $\mathbb R$, consider $x^2(x-1)^2+y^2$. It is irreducible, but its zero set is reducible.

In the first case, the field is too small, and in the second case the variety is singular at its real points.

Now in your case, (you are supposed to know that) $f:=\det -1$ is irreducible (over $\mathbb C$), and it defines a smooth variety (it is a Lie group). I claim that under these assumption, the ideal of $V(f)$ is irreducible. 
In what follows, by algebraic varieties over $\mathbb R$, I mean schemes of finite type over $\mathbb R$, not only real points.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ be a smooth geometrically irreducible variety over $\mathbb R$ such that $X(\mathbb R)\ne \emptyset$, then $X(\mathbb R)$ is *Zariski* dense in $X(\mathbb C)$.

*Proof*: Let $g$ be a regular function on $X$ vanishing at $X(\mathbb R)$. Take any $x_0\in  X(\mathbb R)$. By the implicit function theorem, in a small *analytic* neighborhood of $x_0$, $X(\mathbb C)$ is isomorphic (as complex analytic manifold) to an open disc $D$ in $\mathbb C^d$ with $d=\dim X$. Moreover, this isomorphism is defined using real coefficients, so it induces an isomorphism on the real points. Therefore, $g$ can be viewed as a holomorphic function on $D$ which vanishes at the real points of $D$. This implies that $g=0$ on $D$. But $D$ is Zariski open in $X(\mathbb C)$, so $g=0$.

Now we can prove the claim. Let $g$ be a real polynomial such that $g(V(f))=0$. Let $X$ be the algebraic variety over $\mathbb R$ defined by $f$. Then $g$ is regular on $X$ and vanishes on the real points of $X$. So $g=0$ on $X$. By the usual Nullstellensatz, this implies that 
$$g\in (f\mathbb C[x_1, \dots, x_n])\cap \mathbb R[x_1, \dots, x_n]=f\mathbb R[x_1, \dots, x_n].$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Also:
1) I'm not sure what you mean by $X(\mathbb{R})$ or $X(\mathbb{C})$?
2) What makes the algebraic variety defined by $f$ a smooth geometrically irreducible variety, if the second counterexample isn't?

Comment: When $X$ is defined by a real polynomial $f$, then $X(\mathbb R)$ is the real zeros of $f$ and $X(\mathbb C)$ the complex ones. For your $f$, $X$ is smooth because it is a group variety (this could also be check by Jacobian criterion with the Jacobian matrix). In the second counterexample, the Jacobian matrix is zero at the only real points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: I think I understand. Could you perhaps point me to something that contains this proof? It's for a thesis.

Comment: These are somehow basic algebraic geometry results, I don't know whether there is a place where this is written. Maybe you can just quote this answer ?

Comment: I could! Let me just make sure: you prove that $\mathcal{I}(\mathcal{V}(f))$ is the principal ideal of $f$, right? And this entails that $\mathcal{V}(f)$ is irreducible. At least for the case $F=\mathbb{R}$, which is what I need. (Would you mind explaining what regularity and geometric irreducibility means?)

Comment: We really need $F=\mathbb R$ here (maybe some sort of "ample" or "large" field could be enough). It is proved here that $I(V(f))$ is generated by $f$. This implies $V(f)$ is irreducible. Regularity of a function $g$ just says $g$ is a polynomial function (see any book in algebraic geometry for the term "regular function on an affine variety"). To say that $f$ is geometrically irreducible means it is irreducible over $\mathbb C$. For example, $x^2(x-1)^2+y^2$ is irreducible as real polynomial, but not as complex polynomial.

Comment: I'm trying to piece an argument together from what you have told me here. I'll post it as an answer when I think it's done. Thanks for everything so far!

Comment: Do you perhaps have a reference for the version of the implicit function theorem that you use?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14060/discussion-between-bryder-and-cant-log)

Answer (score 1):

To show: $SL(n, F)$ is irreducible for $F$ an infinite field.

Consider the regular map from $GL(n,F)$ to $SL(n, F)$,
$$\phi\colon A \mapsto A_1$$
where $A_1$ is obtained from $A$ by dividing the first column of $A$ by $\det A$. Now $\phi$ is a regular map ( a rational map with denominators involving the $\det$). Now we only have to observe that $GL(n, F)$ is a (principal ) Zariski open subset of $M_n(F)$. Since $M_n(F)$ is irreducible ( every two non-void open subsets intersect, we are using $F$ infinite), so will be any open non-void subset. Now use that the image of irreducible is irreducible.